# Will i get performance improvement in migration lucene index from v3 to latest v7

Tags: java, performance, indexing, solr, lucene

Our application is indexing books. When we index, the size on disk is around 1GB. When we search, it is taking around 12-18 seconds.

This application was built with Lucene 3.x.x. Will I get a performance improvement if I migrate to Lucene 7.x.x?

I am asking because the application is very big, and separating this piece of functionality is a very big task, so wanted help from experienced people.

I also see many classes which are used in the code that are not available in Lucene-7. How do I migrate? Do I need to do the incremental migration like v3 -> v4 -> v5 -> v6 ->v7?

Comment: What is your index like (how many fields, what type, etc)? 1GB is very small, so what type of performance do you want to achieve? Where is the current bottleneck? (Your search times seem bizarre slow) How many hits do you process? Do you get the docs as well? etc.

Comment: 12 to 18 seconds to search 1GB sounds like something is wrong. How many documents are we talking about? That should usually be a sub-50ms operation.

Answer (score 0):

**Would I see a performance improvement moving to Lucene 7.0**

Impossible to say with certainty, but it's likely you would. There have been considerable performance improvements since Lucene 3. You can browse the [Lucene benchmarks](https://home.apache.org/~mikemccand/lucenebench/), where, scrolling back, you will see improvements on most of them since v3.

Whether it would be *enough* of an improvement is another question. The first place you should look, is if you are using queries that are generally poor performers, and how you could do that better. If you are using a lot of leading wildcard queries, a newer version of Lucene isn't going to magically save you from yourself.

**How do I migrate?**

There is a lot that's changed in the 7 years since Lucene 3. Getting a reader or writer has changed, not even the Documents and Fields work quite the same!  Best thing to do is acquaint yourself with the Migration Guides, which calls out the changes that are likely to break your code, and what to do about them:

- [4.0 Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html)
- [5.0 Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/MIGRATE.html)
- [6.0 Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/MIGRATE.html)
- [7.0 Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_0/MIGRATE.html)

**Do I need to do the incremental migration**

With this many versions to go through, I would rather reindex if possible, but if that's not an option, yes, you will need to upgrade your index one major version at a time. The command line [IndexUpgrader](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexUpgrader.html) tool is what you will need to do that, and it only upgrades from the last major version. So, yes, you will need to download lucene 4, run IndexUpgrader to get a 4.0 index, then repeat with Lucene 5, etc.